# Is DC's The Creeper's yellow skin and green hair a reference to the "Canary Girls" of World War I?

Tags: dc

I recently learned that, during World War I, they found that the women working on TNT shells developed yellow pigmentation to their skin and green hair, leading to the nickname of [Canary Girls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canary_girls) (the trait was sometimes passed on to their gestating babies as well if they were pregnant).

DC Comics's [The Creeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creeper_(comics)) sports a similar color scheme. Is there an intentional reference there? Or is it just coincidental coloring that might stem from there being only so many colors in the palette?

Comment: Can I just [blow your mind](http://www.jewwatch.com/images/Entertainment%20Pics/gif-krusty-the-clown.jpg)?

Comment: Just a note - the article you link indicates the 'Canary Girls' were in World War One, not WWII.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Will fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Not likely. Steve Ditko, the creator of the Creeper had a penchant for creating exotically colored (let's say garish and call it a day) characters who had unusual powers, costumes and backstories including [the Creeper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creeper_%28comics%29), [Mr. A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._A), [Shade the Changing Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shade,_the_Changing_Man), [Hawk and Dove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawk_and_Dove), [Starman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starman_%28comics%29#Prince_Gavyn), [Doctor Strange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Strange), [the Question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_(comics)) and many others.

[image]

> Ditko moved to DC Comics in 1968, where he co-created the Creeper in Showcase #73 (April 1968) with Don Segall, under editor Murray Boltinoff. DC Comics writer and executive Paul Levitz observed that Ditko's art on the Creeper stories made "them look unlike anything else being published by DC at the time." Ditko co-created the team Hawk and Dove in Showcase #75 (June 1968), with writer Steve Skeates.

Ditko was inspired by the strange. He explored exotic ideas like split personalities and characters who were often in the grip of psychosis. Many of his characters existed outside the superheroic norm. The first origins of the Creeper don't seem to include any references to being born this way. The original look of the character was a costume he put on to get a story.

[image]

Comment: Hawk and Dove... aka "The Ambiguously Gay Duo".

Answer (score 4):

No.

There are no links that I'm aware of (or that I could discover by refreshing myself on the character at the DC Wiki or main wikipedia page) between the Creeper and the WWI Canary Girls.

It's even less likely because the Canary Girls was a British phenomenon, and DC Comics isn't noticeably influenced by any of the United Kingdoms.

The Creeper's look is largely based on the Joker's, as his origin typically (like most superheroes, it has changed as time passed) is directly related to Joker's.  His hair is green like Joker's, but they changed his skin coloration to yellow/orange so that close-in panels would still have an obvious distinction between the crazy green-haired, grinning man and the Joker.